# Creating empty lists with comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I would like to receive some help with this code:

```
from datetime import datetime

flights = {
'09:35' : 'FREEPORT',
 '09:55' : 'WEST END',
 '10:45' : 'TREASURE CAY',
 '11:45' : 'ROCK SOUND',
 '12:00' : 'TREASURE CAY',
 '17:00' : 'FREEPORT',
 '17:55' : 'ROCK SOUND',
 '19:00' : 'WEST END' }

def convert_to_ampm(time24: str) -> str:
    return datetime.strptime(time24, '%H:%M').strftime('%I:%M %p')

flights_copy = {}


for k, v in flights.items():
    if v not in flights_copy:
        flights_copy[v] = []
    flights_copy[v].append(k)


for k, v in flights_copy.items():
    time = []
    for item in v:
        time.append(convert_to_ampm((item)))
    print(k.title(), ':',time)
```

***is there a way to make this code written in comprehension:***

```
for k, v in flights.items():
    if v not in flights_copy:
        flights_copy[v] = []
    flights_copy[v].append(k)
```

I'm currently learning Python and I'm not very knowledgeable and I'm also sorry for my poor English skills. Thanks!

---

Comment: What is the end result you want to achieve? If I understand correctly, you would want a dictionary where the key is the destination, and the value is a list containing the hours at which flights fly to that destination. For instance: FREEPORT: ['09:35', '17:00]. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, I just want to minimize the code to make it somehow cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a single comprehension, you can do it at least this way:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

flights_copy = {
    v: [i[0] for i in d]
    for v, d in groupby(sorted(flights.items(), key=itemgetter(1)), itemgetter(1))
}
```

So if flights is: `{1: 20, 2: 20, 3: 10, 4: 15}` then the code above produces: `{10: [3], 15: [4], 20: [1, 2]}`

However, your initial code is readable and works fine.  You could improve it a little by doing it as:

```
from collections import defaultdict

flights_copy = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in flights.items():
    flights_copy[v].append(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to do this is with `defaultdict` IMO:

```
from collections import defaultdict

flights_copy = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in flights.items():
    flights_copy[v].append(k)
```

Doing it with a comprehension is possible but more difficult -- a straightforward comprehension will overwrite the values rather than appending them:

```
>>> {v: k for k, v in flights.items()}
{'FREEPORT': '17:00', 'WEST END': '19:00', 'TREASURE CAY': '12:00', 'ROCK SOUND': '17:55'}
```

so you need a nested comprehension, with an inner list comprehension that builds the list of values for each key:

```
>>> {v: [k for k, val in flights.items() if v == val] for v in flights.values()}
{'FREEPORT': ['09:35', '17:00'], 'WEST END': ['09:55', '19:00'], 'TREASURE CAY': ['10:45', '12:00'], 'ROCK SOUND': ['11:45', '17:55']}
```

Note that this is less efficient because now you're looping over the original dictionary multiple times (it goes from O(n) to O(n^2)).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not with dictionary comprehension but by using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which is quite readable in my opinion:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> flights_copy_2 = defaultdict(list)
>>> for flight_time, flight_dest in flights.items():
...     flights_copy_2[flight_dest].append(flight_time)
...
>>> print(dict(flights_copy_2))
{'FREEPORT': ['09:35', '17:00'], 'WEST END': ['09:55', '19:00'], 'TREASURE CAY': ['10:45', '12:00'], 'ROCK SOUND': ['11:45', '17:55']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!